# How do I get VS code to work with a Pybuilder python project?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pybuilder

- [Pybuilder](https://github.com/pybuilder/pybuilder), around since *2013*.
- The [VS Code Python Plugin](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python), developed by Don Jayamanne in 2016 and now an official plugin!

The default PyBuilder layout looks like this:

```
build.py
\ src
  \ main
    \ python
        \ <python packages, etc.. >
  \ unittest 
    \ python
        \ <python unittests, etc.. >
```

(If you don't understand what PyBuilder is what why the layout looks like this, please go read the PyBuilder documentation.)

How do I make VS Code open the whole project and then recognize only `src/main/python` and `src/unittest/python` as source folders?

In other words, if I have a package `pete` in `src/main/python/pete` and a module `dog` in `pete`, then I want to be able to have a file (e.g. `test_pete.py`) in `src/unittest/python` and use `import pete.dog` in that file.

Comment: What about starting a project and use 'add folder to workspace' on these two folders?

Comment: @olinox14 You haven't actually tried that, have you? ;)

Comment: You're right, I did'nt tried. I did now, but I'm not sure to understand your need. What do you mean when you say 'recognize as source folders'?

Comment: I suppose this is a reference to the JetBrains products where you can easily include any folder as a root folder for source code (or tests).

Answer (score 1):

Start by creating a `.env` file right in the root project.
Then add these lines to it:

```
PYTHONPATH="./src/main/python;./src/unittest/python;${PYTHONPATH}"
```

For Linux / MacOS, replace `;` with `:`.

More details here:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_use-of-the-pythonpath-variable

Comment: This assumes that I want to use `venv` -- which I don't.  Don't get me wrong, `venv` is great, but not part of the answer here.

Comment: Right. Meant to write `.env` and ended up with `.venv`. The answer should be better now.